# Handlebars conditional style attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using `ember 1.8.1`

The controller has a property `isDisplay`

In handlebars, I implement like this, it works but code is too long

```
{{#if isDisplay}}
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
{{ else }}
    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

I tried to using conditional, like this but it doesn't work

```
<div class="form-group" {{bind-attr class="!isDisplay:'display:none;'"}}>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just do `<div class="form-group" {{#if isDisplay}}style="display:none;"{{else}}''{{/if}}>`?

Comment: You are using a version of Ember.js, which was released in 2014 (sic!) and isn't supported anymore for years. `{{bind-attr}}` was deprecated in 1.13, which was released in 2015 (sic!). I would strongly recommend an upgrade.

Comment: Clarity: I think it should be `<div class="form-group" {{#if isDisplay}}''{{else}}style="display:none;"{{/if}}>`. But, it still doesn't work

Error message: `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null` in function `hydrateMorphs`

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is

```
<div style={{unless isDisplay "display: none;"}}></div>
```

But, Ember will throw a warning for binding styles directly to the element. See [Binding Style Attributes](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes)

Hence creating a class and toggling it will be safest and cleanest way.

```
<div class={{unless isDisplay "hide"}}></div>
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: `<div style={{unless isDisplay "display: none;"}}></div>` This still doesn't work. Error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'fn' on string 'display: none;'`

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer (thanks to mukilane):

This does NOT work because `{{# }}...{{/}}` inside a tag is not valid

```
<div class="form-group" {{#unless isDisplay}}style="display:none;"{{/unless}}></div>
```

This does

```
<div style={{unless isDisplay "display: none;"}}></div>
```

Comment: Using a block {{# }}...{{/}} inside a tag in not valid, and will throw an error.

Comment: @mukilane That is not true my friend.

Comment: See [A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block](https://github.com/glimmerjs/glimmer-vm/blob/7cfb662e0331335674b9383c846240b6d8c1feb5/packages/%40glimmer/syntax/lib/parser/handlebars-node-visitors.ts#L80).

Comment: This doesn't work. Same result like Clarity's comment, an error `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null` in function `hydrateMorphs`

Answer (score 0):

As @mukoilane suggested, your safest approach is to toggle a CSS class. If you're using Bootstrap, you can take advantage of the `d-none` class.

```
<div class="form-group {{unless isDisplay "d-none"}}">
  ...
</div>
```