# How to display handlebars condition inside html code style

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars inside HTML backbone.js template. My code is the below :

```
{{for ZippedChoiceResultsArray}}
    <i class="select-btn material-icons unchecked waves-effect" style="color:#558b2f;{{if #data[1]}}display:none;{{/if}}" title='{{>~T("StepListTemplateTmpl","ChoiceSetsDone")}}'>check</i>
    <i class="select-btn material-icons checked waves-effect red-text text-darken-4" style="{{if !#data[1]}}display:none;{{/if}}" title='{{>~T("StepListTemplateTmpl","ChoiceSetsReworkRequired")}}'>flash_on</i>
{{/for}}
```

The error is in the declaration of the handlebars condition inside the style attribute of the `i` tag. I don't know how to fix it and the release is in two days.
Can anyone help or suggest a solution or share a documentation that can help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer might be useful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604391/handlebars-conditional-style-attribute]

Comment: Thank you. There was no problem with the code but VS Code was displaying it as a syntax error because the feature of style validating was turned on.